# Raspberry pi boot stuck at udevd

Tags: boot, boot-issues, upstart

Currently my raspberry pi, running Raspbian, won't fully boot up because its getting stuck 5 seconds into boot at `udevd[107] starting version 175`

Everything was running smoothly until I installed `upstart` to run my node server on the pi.

I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

Once it was installed I was getting `Unable To Connect To Upstart: Failed To Connect To Socket /Com/Ubuntu/Upstart: Connection Refused` error which I solved by [running](https://www.nesono.com/node/368):

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
ln -s /bin/true /sbin/initctl
```

After running those commands I rebooted and got stuck at boot at `udevd`. Any advice other than flashing new raspbian image?

Comment: Anything interesting above the last line? Maybe a screenshot (as in a photo of the screen :) could help? Also: which OS? The link you followed perhaps does not apply to your case, it seems hackish to me.

Comment: the comments against that blog post for the fix complain that "the distro don't boot afterwards" so I suggest you revert your change and try something else.

Comment: @rob I just read that. If I mount the sdcard from the raspberry pi on my mac could I link /sbin/initctl to /sbin/initctl.distrib from terminal?

Comment: I cannot see why not

Comment: So I mounted the sdcard and linked that file to no avail. Any idea how can i relink the file that upstart changes?